# Making a special Sankey Diagram in Python

Tags: python, charts, graphics, replication

I'm an amateur student of Python and I'm intensely drawn to charts there.

I want to make a Sankey Diagram in Python and I was watching videos about this in Youtube but... I think most of them just show a really basic form of this.

Specifically, my goal is to replicate this chart:

[Sankey Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjMvT.jpg)

Please can you give me a link, video or tutorial about that? As you can see, this diagram has more nodes than normal.

Note: I don't care about the exact numbers of the dataset behind that chart. I just want to be able to make other one similar than these.

Regards,

Juan.

To replicate a Sankey Diagram

Comment: Please see/repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). “Show/tell me how to solve this coding problem” [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). We expect you to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

"Plotly" can make complicated Sankey Diagrams. But I am not sure if it can meet all your requirement. Here is the link of Plotly-Sankey Diagram in Python. There are some samples in it. Just have a look.

https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/